# catch an exception an throw another one... is there any other way?

Tags: php, exception, laravel

In Laravel framework whenever you try to fetch some data from your eloquent model, if an exception occurs, it'll throw a`ModelNotFoundException`. In my project I need to catch this exception and redirect user to specific route.

the solution that I've ended up is like this:

```
try{
        $foundUser = $this->user->whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
    }catch(ModelNotFoundException $e){
        throw new NonExistantUserException;
    }
```

I know that I can put my redirect code inside the catch block, however I'm already catching these sort of exceptions in global.php:

```
App::error(function(NonExistantUserException $e)
{
    return Redirect::back()->WithInput();
});
```

I want to know is there any way to say, for example **no matter what kind of exception would occur inside try block** I want to catch it **as** `NonExistantUserException` **just** for this try block!

I'm asking because **catching an exception an throw another one**. seems a bad practice to me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's not necessarily bad practice. Converting one exception to another (by way of catching it) is a perfectly cromulent thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not bad practice and even common practice. But you should not simply discard the previous exception as it might be useful for debugging purposes.

```
<?php

try {
    $foundUser = $this->user->whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    throw new NonExistentUserException(
        "Could not find user for '{$id}'.",
        null,
        $e // Keep previous exception.
    );
}
```

This ensures that you have the full chain of exceptions at your disposal. Other than that your approach looks good to me.

Comment: thanks @fleshgrinder .. I know that the first parameter is the message but, what about the second parameter?

Comment: That's the exception code. You can use it to clearly identify an exception. This is especially useful if a method might throw the same exception more than once and you want to catch only a specific case. `try{}catch(\Exception $e){if($e->getCode()===42){/* do something */}else{throw $e}}`

Comment: Thanks @Fleshgrinder .. now this exception thing makes more sense to me